# Mono UnixSignal.WaitAny blocks forever

Tags: linux, multithreading, mono

I have a C# program that runs in mono 4.6.2 on a 64-bit (x64) Linux platform.  I have this simple piece of code that runs in a separate thread:

```
UnixSignal[] fSignals =
{
    new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGINT),
    new UnixSignal(Signum.SIGTERM)
};

while(!done)
{
   //wait 100ms for any signal
   //The mono WaitAny implementation on UnixSignal returns the timeout you requested
   // instead of WaitTimeout as the rest of the known universe does:
   // http://50.198.40.26/1.1/handlers/monodoc.ashx?link=M%3aMono.Unix.UnixSignal.WaitAny(Mono.Unix.UnixSignal%5b%5d%2cSystem.Int32)
   int index = UnixSignal.WaitAny(fSignals, 100);

   DoSomeWork();

   if (index == 100)
       continue; //no signal

   Signum signal = fSignals[index].Signum;

   //process signal
}
```

The code works fine when program is idle, but when other parts of the program are even moderately loaded the WaitAny() call blocks forever and DoSomeWork() never gets called.

I used strace utility to see what's going on and isolated the output from signal-processing thread and I see this line over and over:

```
poll([{fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=8, events=POLLIN}], 2, 100) = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
```

The last argument is the 100ms timeout that we specify. Since I don't see any other value what I think is happening is that when poll is interrupted by a signal, such as SIGPWR widely used by Mono, poll restarts with the same timeout until it is interrupted again and again. If it it interrupted often enough user process remains blocked for way more than 100ms.

Is it a bug in Mono or is there something else going on?

Thank you.